# "git init" giving error "C:/Users/Filler_name/Documents/DNN_TEST/.git: No such file or directory"

Tags: windows, git

When I try to use the "git init" command in Git Bash, it tells me the file does not exist. I am using Git Bash 2.23, and I still get the error using 2.22 and 2.21.

I have reinstalled Git, restarted my computer and cannot think of another reason why. A colleague of mine is able to git init and git clone our repo in less than a minute.

What could possibly be causing this error?

Comment: Do you have `git` on your Windows search path?

Comment: The peculiar thing here is that Git seems to already know where the repository is / should-be. Do you have `$GIT_DIR` set in your environment? (If so, why?)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I do have git on my PATH variable.

Comment: @torek I do not have $GIT_DIR set. This issue applies to multiple things, such as when i try to run mkdir, it retuns "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘directory’: No such file or directory", I feel like this issue might be larger than git

Comment: Yes, that definitely sounds more general. Do any file system write operations work? Perhaps your drive is read-only for some reason?